# Recursive algorithm time complexity (maximum independent set)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have an assignment to analyse and implement an algorithm for finding the maximum independent set of a graph, and I've come to the time complexity part of said algorithm. I've deduced it is as follows:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-3) + O(n^3) + O(n^2)
```

I've figured some other similar recursive algorithms out before, but I got stuck several times with this one. I think it's supposed to turn out to be ~O(2^n).

Can someone help me get the solution?

Edit: I just double checked it the solution is supposed to be O(1.8^n). Any way to get to that solution?

Comment: The homogeneous part is going to be [powers of 1.46557...](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/step-by-step/x%5E%7B3%7D%3Dx%5E%7B2%7D%2B1). The non-homogeneous part is O(poly(n)), so I don't see how we get O(1.8^n) except by using the fact that big-O is an upper bound only.

Answer (score 2):

Since O(n³) + O(n²) = O(n³) = O(f(n)) where f(n) = n³ − 12n² + 30n − 28,
there exists some constant γ > 0 such that we can overestimate the
original recurrence T as a concrete linear non-homogeneous recurrence
T′:

> T′(n) = T′(n−1) + T′(n−3) + γf(n).

We follow the usual playbook, focusing on the homogeneous part first
(same recurrence but without γn³). The characteristic polynomial is x³ −
x² − 1. Letting α be any zero of this polynomial, the function
α<sup>n</sup> satisfies

> α<sup>n</sup> = α<sup>n−1</sup> + α<sup>n−3</sup>,

Assuming that the base case values are positive, the growth rate of the
homogeneous part will be Θ(α<sup>n</sup>) where α = 1.46557… is the zero
of maximum argument.

We also have to deal with the non-homogeneous part, but it turns out not
to matter asymptotically. By design we have f(n) = (n−1)³ + (n−3)³ − n³,
so letting U(n) = βα<sup>n</sup> − γn<sup>3</sup>, we can verify that

> U(n−1) + U(n−3) + γn³ = β(α<sup>n−1</sup> + α<sup>n−3</sup>) −
> γ((n−1)³ + (n−3)³ − f(n)) = βα<sup>n</sup> − γn³ = U(n)

is a solution for T′, keeping us in the same asymptotic class.

Comment: For folks looking at this answer and trying to generalize it - the choice of f(n) in that first step is designed so that U(n) = an^3 + bn^2 + cn + d and so that U(n) - U(n-1) - U(n-3) - gamma n^3 = 0. You can then solve for the coefficients using standard techniques. (@DavidEisenstat - is that correct?)

Comment: @templatetypedef Yes.

Answer (score 0):

If we draw the recursion tree, it will look something like this, For simplicity, lets every node has 2 child nodes and the height of this tree is ***n*** until it reaches the base case. As it's a binary tree the number of nodes will be **(2^n)-1**.
So the complexity for **T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-3)** is **O(2^n)**.

[image]

Now the overall complexity is **O(2^N) + O(n^3) + O (n^2) = O(2^N)**

Comment: Thanks, it's a bit easier this way with a graphical approach. Now if I may ask, is there a way to find a more precise result (namely the exact complexity is O(1.8^n) ) ?